# How to search contain in name File C#

Tags: c#, winforms, file, directory

I want to search for the characters in Name file of the Directory. If the content is different from the results found, delete the file. I've tried the code below:

```
private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FileWithFilter(Parth, "Abc123");
}

private void FileWithFilter(string folderName, string filesToExclude)
{
    DateTime dateTime = DateTime.Now;
    DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(folderName);
    foreach (FileInfo fi in dir.GetFiles())
    {
        if (!fi.Name.Contains(filesToExclude))
        {
            fi.delete();
        }
    }
}
```

It works, but if the file in Directory is more than 10 or 11(file), code can't run correctly!
please tell me any better way or other solution.

Comment: Instead of deleting from within the directory enumeration you might try storing the names of files to be deleted in a list and delete them after.

Comment: Define "Can't run correctly". Do you get an error? If so, what is it? If not, in what way is the program not meeting your expectations?

Comment: Ignore the case with `!fi.Name.Contains(filesToExclude, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)`.

Comment: It worked but in correct. when I try more than 10 files. The program delete wrong file with contains the correct . 10 files with name : 1.ACB.tar , 2.ABC.tar, 3ABC.tar ... 10.ABC.tar

Comment: "1.ACB.tar" does not contain "Abc123", so it will be deleted.

Comment: this is example name files. The contain search (ABC). Code i tried works ok but incorrect if files in Folder > 10

Comment: You wrote `FileWithFilter(Parth, "Abc123");` not `FileWithFilter(Parth, "ABC");`

Answer (score 2):

I would propose to save all files which should be deleted in a list and then delete them afterwards. It is not recommendd to manipulate the list you are iterating over.

```
    private void FileWithFilter(string folderName, string filesToExclude)
    {
        List<string> filesToBeDeleted = Directory.GetFiles(folderName).Where(m => !m.Contains(filesToExclude)).ToList();
        filesToBeDeleted.ForEach(m => File.Delete(m));
    }
```

Comment: It worked but in correct. when I try more than 10 files. The program delete wrong file with contains the correct . 10 files with name : 1.ACB.tar , 2.ABC.tar, 3ABC.tar ... 10.ABC.tar

Comment: This should not be necessary, as `GetFiles` returns an array.

Comment: returns an array of strings, so there is also an implicit cast to FileInfo which is unecessary.